# Can multiple datasets write to the same folder one after another?

Tags: apache-spark

I have code which generates a series of datasets from the same SparkSession object and writes them to a folder as Parquet files. I want to see each write materializing a new Parquet file within that folder, but the code seems to hang after the first write.

The code looks like below:

```
// Called in a loop with different values for the dataset parameter
void writeDataset(Dataset[Row] dataset) {
    DataFrameWriter[Row] writer = dataset.write();
    writer.format("parquet");
    writer.save("/tmp/folder");
}
```

The first write does a generate a parquet file and a _SUCCESS file within the above /tmp/folder, but the subsequent calls to the method seem to hang at the save() method.

How do I make multiple datasets each generate one Parquet (or Avro or JSON) file in a folder, when called in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get it to add new files using the SaveMode.Append option on the writer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html